# High-level language for developing applications on Linux

Tags: linux, programming-languages, desktop-application, console-application

On Windows I've been using C#/.NET to develop both quick and simple CLI utilities as well as big WinForms/WPF applications. Visual studio played a big part in this choice but also the language and libraries allowed me to program wide range of applications without much hassle.

I'm now looking for a similar language, or more languages, on Linux. The best choice for GUI, multi-platform applications seems to be QT, usually with C++. For console utilities the best choice seems to be some scripting language like Python. However, C++ isn't a high-level language like C# and many tasks are unnecessarily more complicated (since usually I don't look for high performance in GUI applications) and scripting languages are slower and have a higher startup time.

So, what are your languages/libraries of choice when developing applications for Linux, both ten-minute utilities and large complex GUI systems.

Answer (score 3):

After a 13 year rollercoaster ride through C, C++ and Ruby, I moved to Smalltalk (Squeak and Pharo) for all my development - web, scripting (just starting here), and desktop GUI apps.

Trust me, no one was more surprised than me, but Ruby got me hooked on dynamic languages, and combined with Smalltalk's live environment, I am high on OO Koolaid.  If you've never experienced it, check out this screencast: http://www.pharocasts.com/2010/02/programming-with-live-objects.html

Warning - although the language is beautifully simple, it will take a while to wean off of many unnecessary and complicated, but cherished, distractions e.g. files, databases, compile cycles, etc.  Luckily the community is very friendly and extremely helpful.

Also, Squeak/Pharo run on top of a VM which works in (at least) linux, windows, and Mac, so you can develop (and share) anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Monodevelop, It is C# and offers similar functionality as the one you are used to. And above all: it comes from the same company behind C#.

As you mention: Qt is also a possibility and one I've been using extensively. Of course, you will need to develop in C++ then. The tool you want to look at is qt-assistent.

Comment: Monodevelop most emphatically does not come from the same company behind `C#`. Microsoft wrote C#. Novell and the mono project have created an equivalent implementation of the CLR that can run on more platforms than `Win32`.

Comment: Ah oops, my mistake. In any case, it is remarkable similar as far as the question goes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in wxwidgets, 
http://wxwidgets.org/

regards,
/t

Answer (score 1):

I use python and gtk to develop GUI applications.

With glade as UI editor you can quickly setup your application.

Doing the same thing with python/Qt(or whatever Graphical library you want) should be easily doable as well.

See here : http://docs.python.org/faq/gui.html

Answer (score 1):

Python can make linux system calls; use

```
import os
os.system("yourFavouriteSystemCall")
```

Additionally, PyQt4 gives you simple access to the GUI framework Qt4.   This could be a good bet for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use QT or Wx with Python or some other scripting language

Answer (score 0):

You can either use QT with Python, or Mono since you already have experience on .NET.